# I wrote this simple Restful web-service and am getting a blank response. Why?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am learning to write a Restful webservice in PHP. So I followed a video tutorial and wrote the following basic webservice. The problem is that when I tried to access the web service via `http://localhost/Test8/?name=c` (because my `index.php` is located in `Test8` directory) URL, **I get a blank page**.

But when the tutor in the video accessed it using `http://localhost/rest/?name=c` (because their `index.php` located in `rest` directory), **they got `{"status":200, "status_message":"Book found", "data":348}` in the webpage.**

**What did I miss?**

**index.php:**

```
<?php

//Process client's request (via URL)
header("Content-Type:application/json");

if (  !empty($GET['name'])  ) {
    $name = $GET['name'];
    $price = get_price($name);

    if (empty($price)) {
        //Book not found
        deliver_response(200, 'Book not found!', NULL);
    } else {
        //Send the response with book price
        deliver_response(200, 'Book found', $price);
    }

} else {
    //throw invalid request
    deliver_response(400, "Invalid Request", NULL);
}



 //API Functions
 function get_price($bookRequested) {
     $books = array(
        'Java' => 999,
        'C' => 348,
        'PHP' =>500
     );

     foreach ($books as $book=>$price) {
         if ($book == $bookRequested) {
             return $price;
         }
     }
 }


 function deliver_response($status, $status_message, $data) {
     header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

     $response['status'] = $status;
     $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
     $response['data'] = $data;

     $json_response = json_encode($response);
 }

?>
```

---

**EDIT:**

**Just checked the console. It says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Invalid Request)`...**

I changed

```
if (  !empty($GET['name'])  ) {
    ...

} else {
    //throw invalid request
    ...
}
```

***to***

```
if (  !empty($GET['name'])  ) {
    echo '$GET["name"] is NOT empty';

    ...

} else {
    echo '$GET["name"] IS empty';
    //throw invalid request
    ...
}
```

**and the browser prints `$GET["name"] IS empty`.**

Comment: I see your code doesn't change the PHP array to json with json_encode. Maybe worth a try to add json_encode($price). Personally, I never use deliver response so I don't know whether you need to convert the array or not. Usually I just echo the json encoded array. It is simpler for me.

Comment: it is $_GET instead of $GET

Comment: @Bharata Thank you. Please see the edit in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `deliver_response()` function doesn't actually send the result to the browser. It just encodes the `$response` as JSON and stores it in `$json_response`.

Try adding an `echo $json_response;` to the end of that function.

And then, access your URL: http://localhost/Test8/?name=Java

Comment: Thank you. Can you please see the edit in my question? The `$GET` is empty. =s

Comment: yes, I just added the comment about the $_GET instead of $GET